# Comparison with a polynomial of undetermined real coefficients

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

We have $c>1$ fixed, and $P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ with only negative roots.
In writing a proof, I argued that, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x^n/c-P(x)\right)=-\infty$, then, for large enough $x$, $P(x)>x^n/c$ forever, and so $1/P(x)<c/x^n$ forever. But I was told that:

> A constant is not sufficient, as long as you have no control about the other coefficients. They can either exceed or remain below the borders any specific choice of $c$ gives.

Can someone explain to me how my logic does not hold?

Comment: Any number can exceed a constant by its absolute value.

Comment: Probably the objection is about your presentation rather than about the soundness of the idea itself.  To show $P(x) \gt x^n/c$ for all *sufficiently large* $x$, one needs to show $x^n - x^n/c \gt -a_{n-1}x^{n-1} - \ldots - a_0$ for all sufficiently large $x$.  The terse way you recount your argument here suggests that you might have taken some shortcuts in your assignment, but I'm just speculating.  Your idea can certainly be made to work, e.g. using $\epsilon-N$ arguments.